# WPF application responding very slow on Windows Atom D525 processor, 2GB DDR2

Tags: .net, wpf

I have created a POS application in WPF and it is responding very slow only in Windows Atom D525 processor, 2GB DDR2. I am loading all the data from the JSON files and show it in the dashboard by categories and its subcategories wise. When I click on any category then it takes around 3 seconds to show its subcategory. I am sure it is UI related but not sure what is causing this. On all other Windows system, it is working very fast and shows subcategories in less than a second as there is no API call or database interaction which takes time.

Please let me know if anyone experiencing this kind of issue.

Thanks

Maninder

Comment: In your code, try to add a setting to enable/disable hardware acceleration, https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/feb/13/video-rendering-issues-for-wpf-windows#wpf-processrendermode Then disable it on this machine and try again.

Comment: Could you post the code for others to see and try themselves. Do remember to remove sensitive and/or copyright content.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, I tried setting RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;  in OnStartup and it corrected the rendering of controls on UI before I was facing issue of controls not properly rendered and showing only when i click on it. But the problem of lagging is still there and it takes around 3 secs when i click on Category to show sub categories.

Comment: Then your app faces multiple issues (hardware rendering issue, as well as a performance issue with some event handlers). The latter can only be investigated using tools such as performance profilers.